# Как определить задана ли секция в ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, razor

Во вьюшках в ASP.NET MVC можно определять секции - Section.
А как в мастер вьюшке узнать определена ли данная секция во вьюшке?
Ведь она может быть как задана так и не задана. А я хочу в зависимости от этого выводить разный контент.
Сейчас я через ViewBag передаю дополнительную переменную `ViewBag.IsRightPanelDefined`, но сейчас вот подумал, может быть есть способ просто через мастер страницу узанать задана ли секция во вьюшке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить так:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("SectionName"))
{
    //....
}
```